# <a> tags lack substance in IE, hence breaking css menu

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

When building a site I ran into a strange problem with IE and our css menu system. The a tag in the top tier of the menu seems lack the same clickable area that Firefox and Chrome give it. So because the a isnt adjacent to the sibling ul, hovering shows the ul but as soon as you try to move to the ul it disappears because IE doesnt consider you still hovering over the li that contains the a.

Here is an example page of what I am talking about:
[Problem with IE and CSS menu](http://sandbox.highsitetest.com/examples/problem_with_menu_in_ie.html)

I would like this to work in IE >= 8

Comment: Can you provide relevant code instead of a link to the site only. Now I have to surf through all your code to try and find the issue when you can just snip out the css/html and pop it into the question :) and protip: try not to make your last line sound so "work requesty"

Comment: @rlemon sorry but I didn't feel as though I could distill the problem down further, and I didn't want to post all 273 lines of css since that would 'overcrowd' the post. I figure giving a simple link with essentially just html and css would be more affective as an example.

Answer (score 3):

Include the `:hover` definition on the top level `<LI>` instead of `<A>` - the submenu is not contained within the anchor tag, so it is disappearing when you mouse off of it onto the submenu.

Change from

```
#menuh ul li a:hover
```

to

```
#menuh ul li:hover
```

Comment: if you look at the css, the left attribute (which is used to hide the `<ul` submenu) IS set to auto under `#menu li:hover ul` (line 273 of xm_styles.css) hence dependent on the `<li>` and not the `<a>`. I know the submenu is not contained by the anchor tag, instead it seems the IE has a different definition of what parts of an `<a>` are clickable (margin, padding, etc).